# S3 sink connector creating too many small files when there is a lag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using s3 sink connector to ingest data in s3 with below settings.
"rotate.interval.ms": "3600000"
"flush.size": "2147483647"

It works fine, when there is no lag from kafka published msgs.
however, If there is a lag it starts creating very small and too many files. some of them might have only 2 records.

I want a setting where it runs after 1 hour and try to ingest the data only present in that hour and with max 2 files.

Any suggestions to that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want data to write every hour, use the "scheduled" rotation settings

Comment: I read  that it doesn't give one time delivery  guarantee. so in that case It will be getting duplicate records. what if, I use only flush.size = 25 MB then it will upload only that number of records ?

Comment: Flush size setting is records based, not a file size

Answer (score 0):

Kafka to S3 sink connector with deterministic partitioner should produce the same set of files regardless of the lag. This means you don't have exactly once delivery anyway and scheduled rotation settings won't harm anything. Or you have to  fix the partitioner settings. See [also](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html#exactly-once-delivery-on-top-of-eventual-consistency)